# Equivalence of Yetter-Drinfeld modules to Drinfeld center: is there a purely categorical proof?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, drinfeld-center

Let $H$ be an Hopf algebra over a field $k$, and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the monoidal category of left $H$-modules.
It is known that the Drinfeld center of $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent (as a braided monoidal category) to the category of Yetter-Drinfeld modules over $H$ (recall that the Drinfeld center of a monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ has as objects the pairs $(Y, \phi)$ where $Y$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\phi$ is a natural isomorphism $Y \otimes - \to - \otimes Y$ satisfying a certain compatibility condition with tensor products.) The comodule action on $Y$ is given by $y\mapsto \phi_H(y\otimes 1) \in H \otimes Y$.

You can find a proof of this equivalence, for example in *Quantum Double for Quasi-Hopf Algebras* by S. Majid, Lemma 2.1. The Yetter-Drinfeld compatibility condition arise from the condition that $\phi_H$ is a morphism of modules, together with the observation that right multiplication by any $h\in H$ is a morphism of $H$-modules from $H$ to itself, so that we can use naturality of $\phi$ on right multiplication by $h$.

Now, we can define Hopf algebra objects in any symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{A}$ (the classical case above corresponding to $\mathcal{A}=k$-Vect). We can also define the monoidal categories of $H$-modules or $H$-Yetter-Drinfeld modules over any Hopf algebra object $H$. Everything I wrote above can be rephrased in this categorical language, except for the last sentence, which involves picking elements of $H$. I have not been able to modify the argument in a way that would carry over to this more general setting of Hopf algebra objects, so my question is:

> Let $H$ be an Hopf algebra object in some symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{A}$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of left $H$-modules. Is it true that the Drinfeld center of $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the category of Yetter-Drinfeld modules over $H$?

**Note:** I have been able to reduce the problem to the following claim:
Let $(Y,\phi)$ be in the Drinfeld center of $\mathcal{C}$ and let $X$ in $\mathcal{A}$ be equipped with the trivial module structure (given by $\varepsilon \otimes \text{id} : H \otimes X \to X$ where $\varepsilon$ is the counit).  Then $\phi_X : Y \otimes X \to X \otimes Y$ is equal to the symmetric braiding in $\mathcal{A}$ between $X$ and $Y$.

This is easy to show in the case of vector spaces, by checking that the two maps agree if they are precomposed with the map $t_x: Y \to Y\otimes X$, $t_x : y \mapsto y\otimes x$ for any $x\in X$. Again, this is dependent on taking elements of $X$ and doesn't work in the general case.